# Using progressing bar while scanning image through WIA in C#

Tags: c#, wia

I need to integrate scanner in my C# application. I had done integration of scanner in my application using WIA, but I want to show the status of scanning using progressing bar. Can any one help me that how can I do it in my C# windows application.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms630786%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

by using the :dialog.ShowTransfer you will be able to get a percent dialog of the current scan

```
                scannedImage = dialog.ShowTransfer(item,
                           FormatID.wiaFormatTIFF, true) as ImageFile;
```

there is another option , you can use a BackgroundWorker to monitor the WIA scanning proccess. 
check this example : [from Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/725517/Automatic-Scanner-code-in-Csharp)

Comment: Your code helps me a lot thank you for that, and I need some help, Here there is a "item" in code can you mention that what is the item here

Comment: Item refer to the scanning device you choose when activate the select device dialog. check my code: scanner = dialog.ShowSelectDevice(
                WiaDeviceType.ScannerDeviceType, true, true);
                Item item = scanner.Items[1];

Comment: Thank you fatalica, I got it and it is working fine but there is a small problem scannedImage = dialog.ShowTransfer(item,
                           FormatID.wiaFormatTIFF, true) as ImageFile;  if I use the above code it is scanning two time and it is scanning only some part of the image.

Comment: your question is not very clear, i think its better you inspect the example i gave you and reprase your question

Comment: if my answer provide you the help you need mark it as "V" and for more questions regarding the process open new thread :)